# Finding object ratio (width:length) from OpenCV edges

Tags: image, opencv

I am trying to detect whether a building is square or rectangle. The image is taken from google earth.

Is there a way to determine length or width ratio from OpenCV contours?
I already managed to get edges that match the building (like the picture shown) and the contour length and area but still struggling on finding width and length ratio.

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: use cv2.minAreaRect on the detected contour and get the sides of the minimum enclosing rectangle. Use it to determine the ratio

Comment: Thank You very much! I was able to find the ratio through your suggestion.